# Why did it run as the result?

Tags: java

```java
enum Color {
    RED, GREEN, BLUE;

    // 构造函数
    private Color() {
        System.out.println("Constructor called for : " + this.toString());
    }

    public void colorInfo() {
        System.out.println("Universal Color");
    }
}
```

```java
public class NumTest {
    // 输出
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Color c1 = Color.RED;
        System.out.println(c1);
        c1.colorInfo();
    }
}
```

I thought the result of running was “Constructor called for : RED”
Why is the constructor called three times？

Comment: Interesting question, but could you please paste the full output into your question so we can be sure precisely what we are talking about? In particular I’m not sure whether you are seeing `Constructor called for : RED` three times or you are seeing all three colours?

Answer (score 5):

Enum constants are all initialized as soon as the class gets initialized -- as soon as there's any usage of `Color`.  So all three, `RED`, `GREEN`, `BLUE`, get constructed.

See *Java Language Specification*, [*Chapter 8.9 Enum Classes*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9).